# Zlib сжатие в формате gzip

Tags: c++, c, zlib

Подскажите пожалуйста насчет сжатия библиотекой Zlib данных в формат gzip, а не zlib.

**1**)Правильно ли я понимаю, что при сжатии в формате gzip - Zlib установить в заголовок gzip размер сжатых данных - размер первоначальных не сжатых данных ?
В заголовке же gzip - есть место под размер не сжатых данных ?

Вот тут находил ответ:[Чем deflate отличается от gzip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364068/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-deflate-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-gzip)

Вроде пишут, что есть. Но в гугле, что то больше ничего не нашел по полям заголовка gzip.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

**2**)И собственно интересует, как сделать, чтобы Zlib сжимала в формат gzip.

В описании к deflateInit2 написано:

```
deflateInit2 ((z_streamp strm,
                                     int  level,
                                     int  method,
                                     int  windowBits,  //это
                                     int  memLevel,
                                     int  strategy));
```

> windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip encoding.
> **Add    16** to windowBits to write a simple gzip header and trailer
> around the    compressed data instead of a zlib wrapper.  The gzip
> header will have no    file name, no extra data, no comment, no
> modification time (set to zero), no    header crc, and the operating
> system will be set to the appropriate value,    if the operating
> system was determined at compile time.  If a gzip stream is    being
> written, strm->adler is a CRC-32 instead of an Adler-32.
>
> windowBits также может быть больше 15 для необязательного кодирования
> gzip. **Добавлять 16** в windowBits, чтобы написать простой
> gzip-заголовок и трейлер вокруг сжатые данные вместо оболочки zlib.
> **Заголовок gzip не будет иметь имя файла, без дополнительных данных,
> без комментариев, без времени модификации (установлено на ноль), без
> заголовок crc, и в операционной системе будет установлено
> соответствующее значение, если операционная система была определена во
> время компиляции**. Если поток gzip в написанном виде strm->adler — это
> CRC-32, а не Adler-32.

-Я что то ни как не могу понять, что значит "Добавлять" ?? К чему добавлять ? Каким образом "добавлять" ?

-И возвращаясь к первому вопросу: то есть Zlib сама установить значение заголовка gzip, если ОС будет определена и оставит поля заголовка пустыми, если ОС не была определена ?
А как я узнаю была ли определена ОС или нет ? То есть фактически, как я узнаю были ли установлены значения заголовка gzip или нет ?

***PS: во общем: проверено:***

**a**.Если сжимать данные с помощью Zlib в формате gzip, то Zlib к СЖАТЫМ данным добавляет в последние 4 байта размер НЕСЖАТЫХ данных.

**b**.Чтобы сжать данные в формате Gzip c помощью Zlib - нужно вызвать функцию deflateInit2 с параметром windowBits с значением: 15 + 16

```
deflateInit2(&stream, level, Z_DEFLATED, 15 + 16, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
```

Comment: В смысле «не нашел по полям заголовка gzip»? Целый [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952.html) есть.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, спасибо, я так же нашел ссылку на RFC 1952 в заголовочном zlib.h: https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h, но получается какая то странность. В zlib.h определна структура заголовка gzip - "gz_header_s " и она вроде, ка кне соовтетвует полям описанным в RFC 1952.

Comment: ос не определяется. она записанна константой в коде zlib.

Answer (score 2):

Gzip состоит из заголовка, тела с дефлате, и контрольной суммы. Заголовок можно лепить один и тот же, например, `1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03`.

1f 8b - мэджик

08 - дефлате

нули - FLG|MTIME|XFL

03 - юникс (не имеет значения для бинарных данных)

Указывать размер данных в нем не нужно. Контрольную сумму надо считать во время набивания буфера в дефлате и дописать в конце.

Если хочется указать размер несжатых данных, то он ставится в конце файла после контрольной суммы (ISIZE).

Размер сжатых данных не указывается.

Comment: А что нужно указывать в Gzip заголовке ? И что значит " Заголовок можно лепить один и тот же." ? Лепить из чего ? И кому лепить ?

Comment: недавно игрался с zlib на питоне, распаковывая проприетарный формат... наверное открою хелловорд на си и напишу пример если будет время...

Comment: Я вот никак не могу понять, что значит "если хочется". То есть Zlib сам не заполняет при сжатии ? И еще:нашел ссылку на RFC 1952 в заголовочном zlib.h: github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h, но получается какая то странность. В zlib.h определна структура заголовка gzip - "gz_header_s " и она вроде, ка кне соовтетвует полям описанным в RFC 1952. НАПРИМЕР: в заголовке  "gz_header_s " нет поля под послдение 4 байта в которые помещается размер несжатых данных.

Comment: Несжатые данные в хвосте. В заголовке их нет по рфц

Comment: По RFC 1952 - размер несжатых данных, как раз есть в конце: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-6   - это: ISIZE (Input SIZE).   А вот в структуре "gz_header_s" объявленной в zlib.h - нету.

Comment: header описывает голову, а не хвост.

Comment: 2.3.1. Member header and trailer: ISIZE (Input SIZE) This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2^32.  Не силен в терминах. "Trailer" - это "хвост" ?

Comment: Проверил на Zlib`е. Сжал во общем с параметрами для gzip формата. Действительно Zlib поместил размер НЕСЖАТЫХ данных в последние 4 байта СЖАТЫХ данных!